# how to generate a download link for a file present in amazon S3 using python boto?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

How to generate a download link for a file present in amazon S3 using python boto? I tried (key.generate_url). But it is opening the .txt file in browser instead of download.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

When creating the URL, you should specify a "content disposition" response header:

```
headers = {'response-content-disposition': 'attachment; filename="your-filename.txt"'}
url = key.generate_url(expires_in=600, response_headers=headers)
```

When [the URL is used](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html#RESTObjectGET-requests-request-parameters), it will cause S3 to return a [Content-Disposition header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) that will indicate to the browser that it should download the file instead of display it directly.